# Elements inside ViewCell with diferent margins

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a listview getting elements from a list, the problem that I have is that first item has to have a differentmargin from the second item, like in the image below:

[image]

The even items should be Margin="20,0,0,0" and the odd Margin="0,0,0,0.

My listview is created like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding items}" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemTapped="ListView_OnItemTapped">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="564"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <forms:CachedImage  x:Name="Imagebe"  Grid.Row="0" DownsampleToViewSize="True"  HeightRequest="80" WidthRequest="564"  Source="{Binding Img}" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                            <forms:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" ></TapGestureRecognizer>
                            </forms:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                        </forms:CachedImage>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Take a look at how Gerald handles different templates for odd and even rows here https://blog.verslu.is/stackoverflow-answers/alternate-row-color-listview/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Depechie already mentioned in the comments, this might be a variation to an answer I posted earlier. For the accompanying blog post, please see this: https://blog.verslu.is/stackoverflow-answers/alternate-row-color-listview/

The only thing you need to do is swap out the templates, not having them a different background color, but a different margin.

So, create a DataTemplateSelector, like this:

```
public class MarginDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate EvenTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate OddTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        // TODO: Maybe some more error handling here
        return ((List<string>)((ListView)container).ItemsSource).IndexOf(item as string) % 2 == 0 ? EvenTemplate : OddTemplate;
    }
}
```

And your XAML something like this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AlternateRowColorSample" x:Class="AlternateRowColorSample.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="evenTemplate">
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid Margin="20,0,0,0">
                        <Label Text="{Binding .}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="oddTemplate">
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid Margin="0">
                        <Label Text="{Binding .}" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
            <local:MarginDataTemplateSelector x:Key="marginDataTemplateSelector"
                EvenTemplate="{StaticResource evenTemplate}"
                OddTemplate="{StaticResource oddTemplate}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource marginColorDataTemplateSelector}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">

    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: How are you trying to change them?

Comment: With HeightRequest="80" WidthRequest="564" on grid and image.

Comment: Looks like it might be a bug in XF: https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/issues/830 and https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/issues/854 could you try playing with the `Aspect` property of the image?

Comment: Now is working, I added Grid.ColumnDefinitions and Grid.RowDefinitions  and set the height and width request inside them, and the listview has to have HasUnevenRows="True" , thanks alot for the help.